# How to prove that for all $x$ there exists some $y$ where $ (x^2 + y^2 \geq 0)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

How can I prove that $\forall \,\,x\,\,\exists y\,\,,(x^2 + y^2 \geq 0)$?

Comment: What sets do x and y belong to?

Comment: How about $y=x$ ?

Comment: What is the domain of discourse?

Comment: I assume you are speaking about real numbers. Since $\forall \,\,x\,\,\forall y\,\,,(x^2 + y^2 \geq 0)$, the choice of $y$ is irrelevant.

Comment: How about $y=-\frac{23}{17}$? It doesn't matter what values you assign to the (real) variables $x$ and $y$, the condition $x^2+y^2\geq 0$ is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solutions:

- $y=0$
- $y=1$
- $y=x$

The second one gives you $x^2+y^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if $x \in \Bbb R$, for any $y \in \Bbb R$, especially let $y=0$, it always hods.